# Matlab Extract images from a subplot in .fig format

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, mat

How can I extract images from a subplot figure. fig with images plotted in it? See the subplot of the figure with images formated to png https://ibb.co/60jx8kX

I tried with this code but it didn't give me the output I needed.

```
fig = openfig( 'IC_01.fig' , 'new' , 'invisible' );
imgs = findobj(fig, 'type' , 'image' );
thiscmap = get(fig, 'colormap' );

for K = 1 : length(imgs)
    thisimg = get(imgs(K), 'CData' );
    % now do something with it for illustration purposes
    thisfilename = sprintf( 'extracted_image_%03d.jpg' , K);
    imwrite(thisimg, thiscmap, thisfilename);
end
```

Thank You.

Comment: you attached  png file not a fig file... the image looks like it has several axes objects in it, without the fig file it's hard to tell what type of plot you want., just the phase 2D plot, or also the lineouts? (two different axes), and what about that polar dude there... not clear at all...

Comment: Thanks for the reply, here is the fig file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fSPaYYgZBPQy0pt6Oml36NoAOEqvsWIu/view?usp=sharing and the fig of interest is https://drive.google.com/file/d/1z1Tf3fyONbB0aDxX8P5r17VOV9ltCYbo/view?usp=sharing I want to save the fig of interest into a png file. I am not very familiar with subplots just a beginner in Matlab coding thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's a way to take the data from the first image to the image you want, the first lines are similar to what you did :

```
f=openfig('IC_02.fig')
imgs = findobj(f, 'type' , 'image' );
for n=1:numel(imgs)
    C{n}=imgs(n).CData;
    X{n}=imgs(n).XData; 
    Y{n}=imgs(n).YData; 
    cmap{n}=imgs(n).Parent.Colormap; % not assuming it the same for all axes... 
end
```

Now some of the images will be the colorbar of the image you want (usually one after the other). We then take the Ydata of the colorbar to set the caxis limits of the image you want...  for your case the data was in the 4th "image" object, and the limits are taken from the 3rd "image" (colorbar)...

```
imagesc(X{4},Y{4},C{4})
colormap(cmap{4})
set(gca,'Ydir','normal')
caxis([Y{3}(1) Y{3}(2)])
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I really appreciate it. The code is working well.